# pdftk. Inserting a single page pdf ever other page

Tags: pdftk

I have a pdf that can be any number of pages and each page is different.  How can I insert a second pdf that is only 1 page in length into every other page of the first pdf.  Because its only 1 page, everything i have tried inserts it once, then continues on with the first pdf and never inserts it again.